# Field extension for a given irreducible polynomial $f\in k[x]$ to factorize completely.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, field-theory

Suppose $k$ is a field and $f\in k[x]$ being irreducible. The question (Exercise V.5.13 from Paolo Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter $0$*) asks the reader to produce a field extension of $k$ in which $f$ factorizes into linear factors. The book already gave the construction of a field extension of $k$ in which $f$ has **a** root:
$$
F=\frac{k[t]}{(f(t))}.
$$
$F$ is a field since $(f(t))$ is prime hence maximal. The root is namely the coset of $t$.

My argument is as follows: The existence of the root means $f(p)\in F[p]$ can be factorized as $g(p)(p-t)$. Without loss of generality, assume $g(p)$ is irreducible in $F[p]$. Then consider
$$
F'=\frac{F[p]}{(g(p))}.
$$
Repeat the construction of $F'$ for $F$ until $\deg g=1$.

Does my argument give a valid construction for the desired field (in which the specific polynomial $f$ factorizes completely)? (Note: at this point very little knowledge of field extension and the author wrote that the construction should be 'easy' from the way how $F$ is constructed).

Comment: That's the correct idea. The formal way to write this is using induction on the degree. That way you also don't have to assume every time that $g$ is irreducible. It's just that by induction hypothesis there is an extension (which will be an extension of our base field as well) where $g$ splits into linear factors.

Comment: It is incorrect to “assume without loss of generality” that $g(p)$ is irreducible. Removing a linear factor of $f(p)$, there is *no* general assumption you can make about how the rest of the  polynomial factors. It may be irreducible or it may not. Sometimes the field generated over $F$ by one root of $f(t)$ contains a full set of roots ($x^4-10x^2+1$ over $\mathbf Q$), sometimes it has no additional roots ($x^4-x-1$ over $\mathbf Q$), and sometimes you get intermediate behavior ($x^4-2$ over $\mathbf Q$). Assume $f(t)$ is nonconstant and use an irreducible factor of it to enlarge the field.

Comment: If $k$ is a finite field and $f$ is irreducible means, having one root implies all roots are present. i.e., $k[x]/<f>$ has all roots of $f$. infact if $\alpha$ is a root $\alpha^{q^i}$ are the other roots of $f$ where $|k| = q$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right idea but I'm not quite sure what you have in mind when you say "without loss of generality".  If $g$ is not irreducible, you aren't necessarily done yet, since its factors may still not be linear.  Instead, what you can do is consider the full factorization of $f$ as a product of irreducible polynomials.  If the irreducible factors are not all linear, pick one that is not linear, and adjoin a root of that factor.  Keep repeating this process until all the irreducible factors of $f$ are linear.  (The process eventually terminates since each step increases the number of factors in the irreducible factorization of $f$, and once the number of factors reaches $\deg f$ then all the factors must be linear.)